# How to wait for something with React-Query?

Tags: react-query

I'm new to react query and loving it so far. I get that it is mainly a UI library. So it's great for handling/displaying errors, loading states. But often I find myself wanting to wait for some specific action in an async way. So, I'd love to be able to wait for a promise to return before triggering an action e. g. a redirect.

Here is an example:

```
const NewPostForm = props => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const mutatePostInfo = useUpdatePost(); // useMutate hook
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    mutatePostInfo.mutate(value);
    // I WANT TO: wait for the action to complete before redirecting
    history.push("/new-route/")
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `mutate` function returned by `useMutation` takes options as a second argument, and you can use the `onSuccess` option to execute something when the mutation succeeds:

```
mutatePostInfo.mutate(
    value,
    {
        onSuccess: () => history.push("/new-route/")
    }
);
```

There is also the `onError` (for errors) and the `onSettled` callback (if you want to redirect in case of success or error).

Comment: I came here looking for something else, but I am not applying this to my code too lol

Comment: Addition: If you want to `await` for resolving `mutate`, you can wrap the whole call in a Promise and resolve it in `onSuccess` (or `onSuccess` / `onSettle`) like this: `await new Promise((resolve) => { mutatePostInfo.mutate(value, { onSuccess: () => resolve() }) });`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Dependent Queries](https://react-query-v2.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries). For instance:

```
// Get the user
const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)
     
const userId = user?.id
     
const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
    ['projects', userId],
    getProjectsByUser,
    {
        // The query will not execute until the userId exists
        enabled: !!userId,
    }
  )
     
// isIdle will be `true` until `enabled` is true and the query begins to fetch.
// It will then go to the `isLoading` stage and hopefully the `isSuccess` stage :)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. **mutateAsync**

`useMutation` comes with a built-in function called `mutateAsync` which you can call it with `await`.
read [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations#promises) for more.

```
const NewPostForm = props => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const mutatePostInfo = useUpdatePost(); // useMutate hook
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
  
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    await mutatePostInfo.mutateAsync(value); // waits for the action to complete before redirecting
    history.push("/new-route/")
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

2. **`mutate` and `onSuccess`**

`useMutation` comes with another function called `mutate`. The second argument of `mutate` is an option that overrides options passed to `useMutation`. the function will fire when the mutation is successful and will be passed the mutation's result. check [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useMutation#:%7E:text=mutate%3A%20(variables%3A%20TVariables%2C%20%7B%20onSuccess%2C%20onSettled%2C%20onError%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20void) for more.

```
const NewPostForm = props => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const mutatePostInfo = useUpdatePost(); // useMutate hook
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    mutatePostInfo.mutate( value, { onSuccess: () => history.push("/new-route/") });
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for waiting for other values or functions to be completed that do not have an onSuccess function, you can use dependent queries to halt the query until that value exists / fits your criteria.

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-dependent-queries-to-delay-react-query-s-usequery-from-firing-on-render

```
const [payload, setPayload] = useState();
const someFunc = () => setPayload("data");

const { data } = useQuery(payload && ["queryKey", { payload }],
    queryName
  );

someFunc();
```

will wait until payload has a value, in this case "data", before it sends it's queryName request, you could also pass in a function with a return value which would wait for that returned value.